# When I try to load a huge report with power bi premium , will it load at one shot from azure storage?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power BI workspace to create a report(table view) with getting data source from azure data lake as a CSV file(1 GB). While customization in the power bi desktop was loading the whole CSV file it cost me on reading it from the azure storage.
My assumption is that while we integrate the report into a power bi workspace or even after embedding it with Power Apps, will that report fetch all the records from Azure lake for each refresh? or is that done caching  for until the next incremental refresh?.

Because if it loads 1 GB of data for each report refresh even if there is no incremental update it will cost me much. So is there any way to avoid the data loading for each refresh until the CSV file updated

Comment: Yes it will do a full refresh each time, it's not a database so can't do incremental refresh on the data

Comment: You can do incremental refresh from a file-based data source, but only if you've got multiple files or folders for the different dates.  And if you do the math on storage transaction pricing you'll probably find that re-reading a 1GB file every day doesn't add up to much. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/